# How to access the cluster IP from one pod to another pod in aws EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am new to AWS EKS and k8s. I am trying to implement the hyperledger network into aws eks. however into that I need to connect pods each other. When I am trying to ping from one pod to another one its not working.

Pods specification: AWS EKS cluster with 2 worker node and pods are in LInux.

How to ping from one pod clusterIP to another one?

Comment: can you explain how are you configuring the services?

Comment: Please provide `YAML` definitions of your deployments and services.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes service IPs are virtual IPs. You cannot `ping` to kubernetes service IPs as there is no endpoint for the IP that can reply to the ICMP ping message. You can only connect to one of the backing pods of the service with `ip:port` combination.

Comment: It this case then why I am getting error like "Failed connecting to {orderer2-service:7050" from other pod?